# Constant arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `Move` class, which is immutable (basically it's just two ints).

The I have class `Moves` with constants:

```
public class Moves {

    public static final Move NW = Move.make(-1, -1);
    public static final Move N = Move.make(0, -1);
    public static final Move NE = Move.make(1, -1);
    public static final Move E = Move.make(1, 0);
    public static final Move SE = Move.make(1, 1);
    public static final Move S = Move.make(0, 1);
    public static final Move SW = Move.make(-1, 1);
    public static final Move W = Move.make(-1, 0);

    public final static Move[] ALL = {
        NW, N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W
    };

    public final static Move[] CARDINAL = {
        N, E, S, W
    };
}
```

I need the arrays for methods such as:

```
public void walkToRandomSide(Move[] possibleMoves)
```

It works nicely, but - obviously - the elements of `ALL` and `CARDINAL` can be changed anytime by anyone. I know the elements cannot be made final, of course.

That is bad - I want this to be a part of a library and as stable and predictable as possible.

How would I work around this?
Make a method that creates a new array each time?

Comment: Why don't you define your constants as enum?

Comment: Create an enum with private constructor!

Comment: I want to iterate over it in a loop, and also I need both CARDINAL and ALL (+ DIAGONAL which I didn't mention here). Enum can't do that.

Comment: See JonSkeet's answer about `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just avoid using arrays. Arrays are *always* mutable, and even if you create a new array each time, that means your callers will have to perform defensive copies if they pass the sets around.

Firstly, I'd change your `Move` class to an enum as Steve suggested. Then anyone can use `EnumSet.allOf`.

Secondly, for `CARDINAL` I would either use `Collections.unmodifiableList` to wrap a list that you'd created internally (and know that you're never going to modify yourself), or use a type which explicitly talks about immutability, such as [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (or perhaps `ImmutableSet`, depending on whether ordering is important or not).

The benefit of using a separate type is that you can then make it clear to callers that it *is* immutable, rather than just documenting that the list that's been returned *happens* to be immutable. While usually it's a good idea to use an interface as the return type, here it's worth communicating a very concrete guarantee in the type system - a guarantee that callers can use in *their* code as well.

Comment: Well, I can't use enum - someone may want to add also moves such as Move.make(2,1) for horse, it can be extended outside Moves. But the immutable lists look like they might work.

Comment: Ok, going with `Collections.unmodifiableList` then, as I don't want to add yet another jar to my project.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are always modifiable (except for zero-size array, as stated in the comment), you should use `Collections.unmodifiableList` here. For example:

```
public final static List<Move> ALL =
        Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(NW, N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W));
```

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas heh, you're right:) Fixed an answer for your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Defensive Copy of the array in the get() method so that no one can change your array:

```
public Move[] getAll{
    Move[] tmpArray = new Move[ALL.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < All.length; i++) {
        tmpArray[i] = All[i];
    }
    return tmpArray;
}
```

or better...

```
public Move[] getAll{
    Move[] tmpArray = new Move[ALL.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < All.length; i++) {
        tmpArray[i] = new Move(All[i]); // make sure to create a deep copy using copy constructor
    }
    return tmpArray;
}
```

Comment: That's okay, don't forget then to make `ALL` private.

Comment: But then I allocate new piece of memory each time the array is accessed, which looks like a bad idea.

Comment: By the way, don't reinvent the wheel, use `System.arraycopy`: `System.arraycopy(ALL, 0, tmpArray, 0, ALL.length);`

Comment: Yes, by allocating new piece of memory we can make sure we have a deep copy of the object, not just shallow copy. Oh by the way, speaking of deep copy, you may want to create a Copy constructor in Move so that you can create deep copies of an existing one.

Comment: I have that constructor, but making a new array each time really smells. I use it in a pathfinding algorithm that is triggered for all monsters on map every game tick. That would be very expensive.

Comment: @user2321930 as OP mentioned `Move` class is immutable, so there's no need to use the copy constructor instead of just copying references.

Comment: I think if you use Collections.unmodifiableList, they are eventually doing the same thing here: iterate through and make a copy of each object. So maybe using unmodifiableList won't be less expensive.

Comment: @user2321930 Of course, it would, because you would just create one unmodifiable list (static final)

Comment: @ginz you are correct... unmodifiableList doesn't create copies but just locks the array. So it is very efficient.

Comment: @user2321930 that's not what I've meant to say, you may just consider this code: `public static final List<Move> = ...` to understand, what did I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Java [enums](http://cyrille.martraire.com/2012/08/java-enums-you-have-grace-elegance-and-power-and-this-is-what-i-love/).  They have far more power than enums in most other languages, being `final` classes with a specific set of `final` members that are the only instances of that class.  If you're using Java 1.4 or older, they're not available, but this is what you want.